# Is there anything wrong with adding a computer to AD before joining the computer to domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain

I've always been taught to stage a domain join: Add the computer to the domain (via AD Users and Computers), in the right area, and then join it. Is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with that.  The primary advantage to that is that it bypasses the default location for new computers.  That advantage (or another that I haven't thought of) may or may not be compelling to you, depending on what policies you have in place in various OUs.

Comment: Staging separates the process (and permissions required) for creating the computer account from the domain join.  So the account performing the join does not need broad permissions in the domain/OU's (aside from the granular join permissions assigned on the specific computer objects when staged).  It also minimizes risk if they automate the process and end up saving the domain join account credentials in a file or an image.